# Use ffmpeg to create a split screen video out of 5 videos- 4 videos in landscape one in portrait

Tags: video, ffmpeg, editing

I'm trying to create a series of split screen videos for students to work on remotely using ffmpeg. I need to create an ffmpeg split screen "template" for 5 videos, 1 in portrait and the other 4 in landscape. 
All the videos have the same resolution: 1280x720. One is 720x1280 (portrait) and the other 4 are 1280 x 720 (landscape)
I want to create a split screen of dimensions 1680x720 out of the 5 videos so the portrait video is 400x720 and the 4 landscape videos as 640x360. 
How do I modify this 2x2 grid ffmpeg code to allow this?:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v][2:v][3:v]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

[image: Split screen dimensions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a layout of:

```
0 1 2
0 3 4
```

Command is:

`ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -i input4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=-1:720[v0];[1]scale=-1:360[v1];[2]scale=-1:360[v2];[3]scale=-1:360[v3];[4]scale=-1:360[v4];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]xstack=inputs=5:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0|w0_h1|w0+w1_h1[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4`

Comment: Great llogan This works if I put in the exact resolutions of each video output. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's the code I used to get the 5 grid working properly
 ffmpeg -i input0.mp4 -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -i input4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=400x720[v0];[1]scale=640x360[v1];[2]scale=640x360[v2];[3]scale=640x360[v3];[4]scale=640x360[v4];[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]xstack=inputs=5:layout=0_0|w0_0|w0+w1_0|w0_h1|w0+w1_h1[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to xstack is using two vstacks to build the portrait columns out of the grid and then hstacking all three together at the end:

```
ffmpeg -y -i p1.png -i g1.png -i g2.png  -i g3.png -i g4.png -filter_complex "[1][2]vstack=inputs=2[p2];[3][4]vstack=inputs=2[p3];[0][p2][p3]hstack=inputs=3" output.png
```